# Are integers faster than strings as keys for lookup tables in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, hash, lookup-tables

My data returned from the backend contains a lot of referential data and I need to access it efficiently, so I'm thinking about creating (object's id) => (object itself) type lookups. The IDs for objects are returned as string and I wonder if integers are faster than strings as hash keys?

```
playerLookup = {};
for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
  var player = players[i];
  playerLookup[player.id] = player;
  // vs.
  playerLookup[parseInt(player.id)] = player;
}
```

According to jsperf test http://jsperf.com/testasdfa, the integer lookup is considerably (~25%) faster on Chrome. Not sure if the test the scenario properly. What do you think?

Comment: Remember that you're using a convertion method which can make it slower.

Comment: You're trying to solve the issue that doesn't even exist, right?

Comment: @RicardoLohmann: Noted. This is a single-page app where the time spent accessing will greatly outweight the initial time spent constructing these lookups.

Comment: Oh I've misread your perf code, nevertheless you don't have to manually `.toString()` it as the interpreter will take care of it.

Comment: In FF 18, the performance is about the same. In Chrome 24 there seems to be a notable difference, so it's only related to the access, since all property names are stored as strings anyways: http://jsperf.com/testasdfa/3. So the answer is: **it depends** which browser/implementation you use (as so often).

Comment: And after looking at the code in your question, I'd say that calling `parseInt` would defeat any performance increase you *might* gain. (yep, http://jsperf.com/testasdfa/4, even a lot slower in FF). *edit: In my previous comment it should read "... **though** it's only..."*.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that the fastest way to find the element is through modular hash tabling.

Make playerLookup an array of n elements, with each element of the array set to -1 (or some value that lets you know that bit hasn't been set yet).

when you store a playerId, store it in `playerLookup[parseInt(player.id) % n]`

The work complexity of finding an item from the hash table this way is 1, but the work complexity of the methods you've listed above is x where x = playerLookup.length (regardless of whether you're using strings or numbers as keys).

To make the hash table smaller, choose a smaller n. The smaller the n, the more likely we'll get clashes.

#### Clashes

To deal with clashes, make each element of playerLookup an array. If you're adding a playerId to playerLookup in a spot that already contains another player, list the new one alongside this one (i.e. now both are in the same spot). If you lookup a player and find a spot in the hashtable with more than one player in it, simply iterate across this array until you find the player. This iteration will be of the same work complexity as the first implementation you had in mind, but with two advantages:

1. It's less likely to even need to happen, because of the modular hash table
2. When it does happen, the array we're iterating across is, on average, n times smaller than the original one you would have implemented (where n is our modulus variable).

For mathematical reasons (with moduli) I recommend choosing a prime number for n.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the code in the question. The OP already uses objects as hash table, that's the `playerLookup[player.id]` part. Why would the access time be `O(n)`?

Comment: Because player.id is a key isn't it? Not an actual address in the array. This means that to find the item the key is mapped to, the system must iterate through every step of the array until it is found (it doesn't just implicitly know every location of every key).

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that objects are implemented as some kind of hash table. Performance does not decrease linearly with the number of properties and the engine does not have to iterate over all properties. Test: http://jsperf.com/big-obj-vs-small-obj.